# JSP page send null value for a forein key parameter

Tags: hibernate, jsp, model, foreign-key-relationship

I have 2 tables, Employee and City .Employee table has a foreign key to City (CityID).
I’m trying to get the CityID value from drop-down list but the returned model from jsp page  always has a null value for CityID;

Employee Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee", catalog = "DataGathering", schema = "dbo")
...
@JoinColumn(name = "CityID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne
private City CityID;
```

City Entity

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "CityName")
private String cityName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "CityID")
private Collection<Employee> EmployeeCollection1;
```

jsp form

```
<td><form:select path="CityID" >
 <form:options items = "${cityList}" itemValue="id"itemLabel="cityName"/>
</form:select></td>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String 
processRegistration(@ModelAttribute("tblEmployee")TblEmployee employee,
BindingResult result,
                Map<String, Object> model) {

    employeeService.create(employee);

    return "employee";
}
```

ERROR:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CityID', table 
'DataGathering.dbo.Employee'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but once change bellow code

```
<td><form:select path="CityID" >
<form:options items = "${cityList}" itemValue="id"itemLabel="cityName"/>
</form:select></td>
```

as,

```
<td><form:select path="CityID" >
<c:forEach item="${cityList}" var="cityList">
   <options value= "${cityList.id}" itemLabel="cityName">${cityList.cityName}</option>
</c:forEach>
</form:select></td>
```

And if you are not getting value in jsp page then change in entity as

```
fetch = FetchType.EAGER
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn't work throws err with same erorr.

Comment: Are you getting city list in jsp page?